# Set else clause for promise if not possible to execute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I currently have a service that gets the user's current location coordinates when they first run my app.

However, if it isn't enabled, I would like the location coordinates to default to null, until the function `setLatLng` is executed, which attempts to derive the user's geocode using the Google Maps API (this hasn't been implemented yet).

The problem I am currently having is creating an error clause for my promise (i.e. nothing has been found so set lat and lng to null). How would I resolve this?

**view.html**

```
<!-- Display if location services is enabled -->
<div ng-if="lat!==null && lng!==null">
    sdfsdf
/div>

<!-- Display if location services is disabled -->
<div ng-if="lat==null && lng==null">
    sdfsdf
</div>
```

**services.js**

```
function LocationService($q, $cordovaGeolocation) {
  var scope = this;
  scope.currentLocation = currentLocation;

  function currentLocation() {

    var q = $q.defer();
    var opts = {
      timeout: 10000,
      enableHighAccuracy: false
    };

    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(opts).then(function success(position) {
      q.resolve(position.coords);
    }, function error(err) {
      q.reject(err);
    })

    return q.promise;
  }
}
```

**controller.js**

```
 function HomeCtrl($scope, $cordovaGeolocation, LocationService) {

   LocationService.currentLocation().then(function success(res) {
    $scope.lat = res.latitude;
    $scope.lng = res.longitude;
   })

   $scope.setLatLng = setLatLng;

   function setLatLng($scope) {
     // attempt to set lat lng here
     //$scope.lat = 0.0;
     //$scope.lng = 0.0;

     console.log(lat);
   }
 }
```

Comment: first of all **services.js** is not optimised. just do `return $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(opts);` or `return $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(opts).then(function (position) { return position.coords; }, function () { return null; });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### services.js

```
function LocationService($q, $cordovaGeolocation) {
  var scope = this;
  scope.currentLocation = currentLocation;

  function currentLocation() {
    var opts = {
      timeout: 10000,
      enableHighAccuracy: false
    };

    return $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(opts).then(function success(position) {
        return position.coords;
    }, function error(err) {
        return null; // this will waterfall into the next then().
    });
  }
}
```

#### controller.js

```
function HomeCtrl($scope, $cordovaGeolocation, LocationService) {
    LocationService.currentLocation().then(function (res) {
        if (res !== null) { 
           $scope.lat = res.latitude;
           $scope.lng = res.longitude;
        } else {

        }
    })

    $scope.setLatLng = setLatLng;

    function setLatLng($scope) {
        // attempt to set lat lng here
        //$scope.lat = 0.0;
        //$scope.lng = 0.0;

        console.log(lat);
    }
}
```

So one key thing here is that you can return promises without having to create new ones in order to chain them!

When you return a value from either success or fail function, the chained `then()` will pick up both returns. If you want to have a subsequent `fail` function picked up you need to `throw` in the first `fail` function. Like so:

```
return $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(opts).then(function (position) {
    return position.coords;
}, function error(err) {
    throw 'no coords';
});
```